# How to mount virtualbox shared folder on solaris?

Tags: solaris

Unable to mount the shared folder from vbox to Solaris machine.
This is usually because the filesystem "vboxsf" is not available. This filesystem is made available via the VirtualBox Guest Additions and kernel module. Please verify that these guest additions are properly installed in the guest. This is not a bug in Vagrant and is usually caused by a faulty Vagrant box. For context, the command attempted was:

mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=1000 keys /keys

The error output from the command was:

mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on keys,
missing codepage or helper program, or other error
In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail or so.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps to create a shared folder on your local (Windows) machine and access it from Solaris Virtual Box:

1. Create one shared folder let say names as "ABC"
2. Go to virtual box click on settings--> Shared Folders
3. Click on "Add new shared folder" button and select "ABC" folder created in the first step.
4. Keep the name in mind and select the option as "Make Permanent"
   [image]

Now go to Solaris Virtual Box and open terminal.

1. Create one folder and give the name as "ABC" (sudo mkdir abc)
2. Use command "sudo mount -F vboxfs ABC /export/home/username/abc"
3. Now you can able to access the shared folder "ABC" from solaris Virtual Box.

Comment: Please note that the abbreviation here is vbox**fs**, as in **f**ile **s**ystem. Not vbox**sf** as the **s**hared **f**older terminology used for the corresponding file system on Linux.